# What this organ (anatomically) is used for?

Tags: sentence-structure

The following question is correct?

> "What this organ is used for?"

This question us supposed to be above a picture of an human organ. The purpose of the question is to get the answer that describe the function of this organ.

- Actually, I didn't find any result of this structure on Google.

Answer (score 2):

The form is not correct for a question. It should be:

> What **is** this organ used for?

As a statement you could use it though:

> If you ask me, I will tell you *what this organ is used for*.

Comment: Could it be that I couldn't find even 3 results on Google with "What is this organ used for?"?

Comment: Maybe "quiz" style questions don't search well, since it would only return pages containing the question.

Answer (score 2):

In reality, you'd likely be understood.

In general, you've stuck a question mark on a statement. This can be done, particularly in speech, because you can raise your pitch at the end of the sentence to make a statement into a question.

Generally in writing, we prefer to rephrase the sentence into the normal question format:

> What is this organ used for?

You could also go for something like:

> What purpose does this organ serve?

Answer (score 2):

According what I see the sentence "What is this used for" is not acceptable in anatomical or phisyological world, these worlds prefer to use by sentence else in this case:

> What is the function of this organ?

Comment: This is not unique to the anatomical world. A textbook on auto repair, for example, would probably not ask, "What is this tappet used for?" but, "What is the purpose of a tappet?" or even, "What does a tappet do?"

Comment: "Used for" triggers culinary associations for me - this one should be ground up for saussage, that one is good on a grill.... ^_^ (provided it's from an animal, of course!)